# Takes a text as input and outputs a list of unique words

Tags: python

```
def clean_up(word):
    return word.lower()

string = "The apple doesn't fall far from the tree"
for item in string:
    print(clean_up(item))

def text_to_unique_words(text):
unique_words = []
for item in string:
    print(clean_up(item))
for word in words:
    unique_words.append(i)
return unique_words

print text_to_unique_words(string)
```

Hi im stuck with the code above. I have to print a sorted list of all the words in a given text string. Each word in the output should be unique, written in lowercase, and no remnants of punctuation marks or white space should be left in the words as printed. The program must contain two functions: text_to_unique_words(text) and clean_up(word). How do I edit this code? I am not allowed to use a import statement

Comment: Please see [how to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0):

For `clean_up`, an easy approach is to filter the characters in the string by `str.isalpha()` and then `join` the resulting iterable back into a single string.  For `text_to_unique_words` you just need to `split` the string, `clean_up` each resulting word, and then `sort` the `set` of the unique words:

```
def clean_up(word: str) -> str:
    return ''.join(c for c in word.lower() if c.isalpha())

def text_to_unique_words(text: str) -> list[str]:
    return sorted({clean_up(word) for word in text.split()})

print(text_to_unique_words("The apple doesn't fall far from the tree"))
# ['apple', 'doesnt', 'fall', 'far', 'from', 'the', 'tree']
```

Comment: It has to work for multiple words with punctuation. How do I code that

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by "multiple words with punctuation" that this function doesn't work for?

Comment: words like Hi!, where? etc

Comment: dots and comma's

Comment: Okay -- how does it not "work" for those words?  Give example input and output.